# Reset Azure Resource Manager Ubuntu VM Password

Tags: linux, azure, ssh, azure-virtual-machine

I have created a Linux VM through Azure Resource Manager (the new model) and now I can no longer SSH into it. The SSH prompt states `Permission denied, please try again.`. Unfortunately I can't reset the password through the portal, so I'm locked out of my machine. Is there a way to reset the password through the CLI?

I found this guide, but it only applies to the classic VM model: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-use-vmaccess-reset-password-or-ssh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to reset your password is through the Azure CLI. There is a good guide here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/blob/master/VMAccess/README.md

Essentially:

1. Download the Azure CLI
2. Create PrivateConf.json file with credentials
3. Run: `azure vm extension set <resource-group-name> <vm-name> VMAccessForLinux Microsoft.OSTCExtensions 1.3 --private-config-path PrivateConf.json`